# Rearranging a Dataset

Tags: dataset

When processing a larger Dataset I came up do a point where I want to form a dataset with culumn heads from an intermediate structure. Here is an example of this structure:

```
test = {<|"name" -> "alpha", 
     "group" -> "one"|> -> {<|"value" -> 459|>}, <|"name" -> "beta", 
     "group" -> "two"|> -> {<|"value" -> -338|>}, <|"name" -> "gamma",
      "group" -> "two"|> -> {<|"value" -> 363|>}};
```

making a dataset:

```
assoc = Association@test; Dataset@assoc
```

this gives:

[image]

Now I´m searching a way to make this a dataset with column-heads "name", "group" and "value". Maybe I´m blind for a moment, but I could not manage it??? Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
test = {<|"name" -> "alpha", "group" -> "one"|> -> {<|"value" -> 459|>}, 
        <|"name" -> "beta", "group" -> "two"|> -> {<|"value" -> -338|>}, 
        <|"name" -> "gamma", "group" -> "two"|> -> {<|"value" -> 363|>}};

Association /@ Flatten /@ Normal[test /. Rule -> List] // Dataset
```

> [image: Dataset]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I´ve simply overseen the step /.Rule->List...o.l. sometimes one does no see the obvious

Answer (score 8):

If we assume that we are starting from the exhibited dataset:

```
dataset = Dataset@assoc;
```

... then we can reshape it like this:

```
dataset[All, Apply@Association]
```

Or, equivalently:

```
dataset[Map[Apply@Association]]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This will also do the trick, although it is a little messy since `MapThread` presently lacks an operator form:

```
dataset[{Keys, Values}][MapThread[Association, #]&]
```

**Edit**

And here is yet another way:

```
dataset[All, <| Keys@#, Values@# |> &]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Dataset[Join@@@({#,Join@@#2}&@@@test)]
(* or  Dataset[Join@@@({#,Sequence@@#2}&@@@test)] *)
```

[image]

Comment: Must be a record for `@@@` density.